# How to break relationship between two list variations?

Tags: 2013, list, variations

I have publishing site with variations as below.

EN (source)
AR (target)

There is a list in EN site copy of which is being made in AR site. Now I want to break this relationship so is there a way to do that using powershell? Because this option is not there in GUI to break the relationship between two list of variation site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the option to disable relationship. It's in the variation settings of "target" list.